# TypeScript test properties of object created within a component's method

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I would like to test a component method.
I would like to inspect an object that is created within that method as it is passed to another method.

I have a component with a method described like so:

```
submit() {

    const goal= new Goal();
    if(component.property == true){
        goal.myProperty ='reached';
    } else { 
        goal.myProperty =' not reached';

    create(goal);
}
```

I would like to inspect the goal.myProperty property as it is being passed to create() method.

Comment: your question is unclear. Please describe more

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, you will have to spy on your method, and see the arguments used for the call. You will have to test the argument properties.

Here is an example :

```
it('should XXX', () => {
  const spy = spyOn(YourImportThatContainsCreate, 'create');
  component.submit();
  epxect(spy.calls.argsFor(0)[1].myProperty).toEqual('reached');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
it('should submit', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'create');
  component.submit();
  expect(component.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining(myProperty : 'reached'));
})
```

Sorry, I haven't tried it myself.